# how to pass session_id() throught out the php pages?

Tags: php, session, sessionid

when user clicks on **login button**(index.php) I am calling **chechlogin.php** where I am checking loginId an password as-

```
if($count==1)
{
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
$_SESSION['UserId'] = $myusername;
$_session['SessionId'] = session_id();
header("location:LoggedUser.php");
}
```

in **LiggedUser.php**

```
<?php session_start();  //starting session
```

if (!isset($_SESSION['SessionId']) || $_SESSION['SessionId'] == '')
  {
   header("location:index.php");
  }
?>

**Problem:** It is always going back to index.php page although I am entering right userid and password.I think session_id() is not working properly or ??

Comment: Are you also calling `session_start()` in your index.php and checklogin.php ?

Comment: yes, at the very first line I am calling session_start() in both pages......is that a problem.

Comment: @Piyush: No, you have to do this ;)

Comment: Variables names in PHP are case-sensitive. $_SESSION and $_session are different variables.

Comment: Plyush please note from Piotr's answer that most of lines you were using in your code are just useless. especially for writing session id into session

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change $_session to $_SESSION.

btw session_register is deprecated and shouldn't be used. See [session-register](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) manual for details.

btw #2. You don't need to store sessionId in the $_SESSION, UserId is enough. So you code could look like:

login.php

```
if ($count == 1) {
    $_SESSION['UserId'] = $myusername;
    header ("location: LoggedUser.php");
    exit;
}
```

loggeduser.php

```
if (empty ($_SESSION['UserId'])) {
    header ("location:login.php");
    exit;
}

// user is logged
```

**EDIT:**
Exit added as Emil suggested.

Comment: I need sessionId so what should I do?

Comment: session_id() will return the same ID for every page as long as it is the same session.

Comment: I am storing the session id in database thats why I need that, I think  in every page I am calling session_start()...thats why session_id() is not working, is it??

Comment: You have to use session_start() on every page. SessionID is stored in user cookie so ID is the same on every page unless browser is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider calling `exit;` after each `header('Location: ...')` call. Otherwise PHP will continue parsing the rest of the code, which may cause unpredictable errors.

```
header("Location: LoggedUser.php");
exit;
```